# -O2 optimization does not go out of the loop if reading large file

Tags: c++, runtime-error, compiler-optimization

I have a very strange problem with GCC (G++) compiler. My C++ code is shown below.

```cpp
int main() {
    ifstream ifsr("some-large-file.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        ifsr.seekg(60000 * i);
        if (i % 1000 == 0) cout << i << "\n";
    }
    ifsr.close();
    return 0;
}
```

It supposed to stop after `i >= 50000`. However, if I compiled the code using `-O2` or `-O3` options, the loop does not stop (it continues iterating, even when `i > 50000`). It works well if I compiled it using `-O` option. And if I commented out the `ifsr.seekg(60000 * i);` line, that also works well (even with `-O2` and `-O3` options). I also tested the code in my AWS instance (EC2 c3.2xlarge with Ubuntu 16.42) and it shows the similar behaviour. (I am using bash for Windows 10).

I have no idea what really happens in this code. And if there is a solution to run similar code without dropping `-O2` or `-O3` options, that would be really great! Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if you are trying to optimise file read/seek speeds, but if you are the compiler optimiser is probably not going to help much.

Comment: This code is just a part of larger codes (which is not shown for simplicity). I use compiler optimisation to optimise other parts of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`49999*60000 = 2,999,940,000` overflows the commonly 32 bit signed `int`. That is undefined behavior and should be the root of the trouble.

For instance, the optimizer is allowed to assume that `i` is never larger than `(2^31 - 1) / 60000` because it can assume UB never happens, and by that logic, the loop condition is always true. (May or may not be *exactly* what happens, UB can break things in all kinds of ways.)

Use `int64_t i` instead.